# Run JavaScript in Android webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I've been trying for several hours to run some `Javascript` in an android webview in which there is `html` parsed by `Jsoup`. And despite all my attempts to make it work, I'm still not able to do it.

I've searched all over Google and tried all the answers I found, however none of them did the trick I tried using a method and here's what I ended up with:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
Elements web_body = doc.select("body").first().children();
Elements web_head = doc.select("head").first().children();

String javascript = "document.querySelector('h1').innerText='f';"; //Replaces 'Example Domain' with 'f': just an example js code.

WebView webview = findViewById(R.id.webview_id);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

String html_content = "<html>" + "<head>" + web_head.toString() + "</head>" + "<body>" + web_body.toString() + "</body>" + "</html>";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html_content, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webview.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null);
} else {
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" + javascript + "})()");
}
```

- The code above shows the example page but javascript doesn't work at all: the app doesn't show any error messages nor crashes.
- I'm using a phone with Android O (8.0).

I hope the above information will be useful. I'm still a beginner in Java and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I replaced:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    webview.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null);
} else {
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" + javascript + "})()");
}
```

with

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView webview, String url) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript(javascript, null);
        } else {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){" + javascript + "})()");
        }
    }
});
```

and it just WORKS!

Comment: looks like it's because the page hadn't yet been loaded when the attempt to run javascript was made. So this doesn't mean we have to call it this way every time - but only when the page was not yet loaded